# While SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, while, sql-server-2012

Buen dia, espero me puedan ayudar.

Necesito hacer la siguiente suma i/(2+j) donde i=8 y j=5 

j=1 

i=1,2...8

0/(2+1) + 1/(2+1) + 2/(2+1) + 3/(2+1)...... 8/(2+1)


j=2 

i=1,2...8

0/(2+2) + 1/(2+2) + 2/(2+2) + 3/(2+2)...... 8/(2+2)

j=3 

i=1,2...8

0/(2+3) + 1/(2+3) + 2/(2+3) + 3/(2+3)...... 8/(2+3)

Y al final sumar los totales de cada while y tener un resultado final de 39.3428. Solo me hace falta hacer la suma de los totales

```
DECLARE @i FLOAT, @x FLOAT, @total FLOAT, @j FLOAT
SET @j = 1;
WHILE (@j <= 5)  
BEGIN
SET @total = 0;
SET @i = 0;
SET @x = 1;
WHILE (@i <= 8)
BEGIN 
   SET @x = @i /(2 + @j);
   SET @total = @total + @x;
   SET @i = @i + 1 ;
   print 'SUB TOTALS : ' + CAST(@total as VARCHAR)+ '-->  i : ' + CAST(@i as 
VARCHAR) + ' , j:' + CAST( @j as VARCHAR); 
END
print 'TOTAL : ' + CAST( @total as VARCHAR)
SET @j = @j + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez más, dejo una enseñanza de como evitar bucles en SQL Server. Para hacerlo, necesitamos una tabla de números (`tally table` en inglés) que permita al motor de SQL Server hacer uso de sus ciclos internos que son mucho más eficientes que los ciclos creados por el usuario.

Una forma eficiente de crear la tabla de números es mediante el uso de CTEs en cascada. Esto es un ejemplo de que no se debe programar igual en SQL que en otros lenguajes.

```
DECLARE @i int = 8,
        @j int = 5;

WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@i + @j) --limitar filas para reducir procesamiento
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT SUM( i.n / (2. + j.n))  -- sumatoria de la fórmula
FROM cteTally i                -- valores de i
CROSS JOIN cteTally j          -- valores de j
WHERE i.n <= @i                -- limitar valores de i
AND j.n <= @j;                 -- limitar valores de j
```

Por cierto, si se quieren mostrar los subtotales junto con el total, se puede usar `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`.

```
DECLARE @i int = 8,
        @j int = 5;

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@i + @j) 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT i.n, SUM( i.n / (2. + j.n))
FROM cteTally i
CROSS JOIN cteTally j
WHERE i.n <= @i
AND j.n <= @j
GROUP BY i.n WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: es un excelente respuesta, desconocía que se podía realizar así

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el error esta en tu WHILE (@j <= 5) donde la variable @total se esta reiniciando cada vez que corre el bucle, esto evita que se sume todos los resultados, probé sacándolo del bucle y tengo un resultado similar al que buscas (esto quizás por el redondeo que tiene el SQL Server), te adjunto el query:

```
DECLARE @i FLOAT, 
        @x FLOAT, 
        @total FLOAT, 
        @j FLOAT;

SET @j = 1;
SET @total = 0;

WHILE (@j <= 5)  
BEGIN   
    SET @i = 1;
    SET @x = 0;

    WHILE (@i <= 8)
    BEGIN
        SET @x = @i /(2 + @j);
        SET @total = @total + @x;

        PRINT 'SUB TOTALS : ' + CAST(@total as VARCHAR(10))+ '-->  i : ' + CAST(@i as VARCHAR(10)) + ' , j:' + CAST( @j as VARCHAR(10)); 

        SET @i = @i + 1 ;
    END

    PRINT 'TOTAL : ' + CAST( @total as VARCHAR(10));

    SET @j = @j + 1;
END
```